# Third party payment gateway in android In app purchase?

Tags: java, javascript, android, iphone, ip

I want to add thirdparty payment gateway in my application for particular thing.can we use third party payment gateway for in app purchase features. please anyone help me

Comment: on iOS third party payment are not allowed if the goods are digital. Only fiscal goods can be paid for by third party payment provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third party payment gateway `can handle your one time purchase` but `can't handle in-app purchase subscriptions`.

so you can use any payment gateway like `PayPal` and handle all purchase subscriptions on `your WebServer` according to your requirement.

i.e.: when the user successfully pays via `PayPal` , you can make an entry on your `WebServer` for that transaction by calling `WebAPI` from android.

Example: [PayPal integration](https://github.com/Joisar/PayPal-Demo)

I hope it will be helpful.